# VB ACCESS Horizontal SUM with specific column

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I would like to ask about VB Access query. In a brief:

here's the source:

[Source of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuCSh.png)
and here's the expected result:

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLApH.png)

I would like to add 1 additional sum column in the end with specified column ( in this case sum of 2 last columns) .

I'm not expert in manipulating data via SQL much appreciate if you guys could help me. it's been 2 days and really stress me out looking for the solution.

Comment: Why first row total is 0?

Comment: @RushabhMaster because the last 2 columns have no value. (No Selling Activity)

Comment: Opps sorry my bad dint read the whole text:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this query in your code
may be this can help you.

```
select *,concat( `032015` + `042015` ,' IDR') Total from yourtable
```

*edit some part to make it works

```
select *, [03#2015]+[04#2015] as total from yourtable
```

remember this 032015 and 042015 is column name not value

Comment: Hi Rushabh, i have tried it and no luck, maybe in SQL it works, idk.. but i tried by removing the concat and just leave the column name + column name as total then it works smoothly.. appreciate your help man!

Comment: Hi Rushabh, btw do you know how to put the total at the end of the columns. Because the result, the total column placed in the first column..

Comment: yes for that use 

`select *, (ColumnName+ ColumnName) as Total from YourTable `

this will place your column at last of table. still you face any problem than show me your result :) thank you @Anthony

Comment: Can you Please try this one?

`select *,concat( [03#2015]+[04#2015],' IDR') as total from yourtable`